# Account Linking not working (Dialogflow)

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have two intents in my Node server (I'm using actions-on -google Node library) to manage account linking flow. The first one looks like this:

```
app.intent("test.login", conv => {
  conv.ask(new SignIn());
});
```

The second one:

```
app.intent("test.login.callback", (conv, params, signin) => {
  if (signin.status === 'OK') {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(conv.user));
  } else {
    conv.ask("Uuups");
  }
});
```

In Dialogflow, I have those two intents in my agent, the second one with the "actions_intent_SIGN_IN" event. The Account linking configuration in the Actions console is this:
[image]

Everytime I do a request in the simulator (or mobile) to the first intent to start Account Linking, Dialogflow returns this error:

[image]

The second intent is executed directly and in the Debug tab of the emulator I see this:

[image]

That url returns an error (500) when is executed.
Anyone can help me to get it to work, please?

Comment: Have you seen the Actions on Google [Account Linking with Google Sign-in docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in)?

Comment: I'm getting same issue please help me anyone.